# resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification not found on adding dataBinding tag

Tags: java, android

On adding the `dataBinding` block in my app-level Gradle file, it shows following errors:

```
Android resource linking failed
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Info not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Time not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Title not found.
error: failed linking references.
```

This app was initially built on eclipse. But now it is running on android studio. The app works fine without the `dataBinding` block. Moreover, there are no errors in style.xml file.

```
// build.gradle (Module:app)    

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 18
        buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "org.irdresearch.iicsystem"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 14
            compileOptions {
                sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
               targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
            }
        }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update compileSdkVersion version from 18 to 29

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution. Not obvious at all.